# How to use nested variable substitution in a hive query

Tags: variables, hive, hiveql, dbeaver

I've tried to use nested variables directly in a hive query. I'm using Hive and Dbeaver.

My goal is to loop through a list of conditions and save the results in numbered tables (condition_1 | tbl_1, condition_2, tbl_2, etc)
Here's an example:

```
@set condition_1 = col1 in (1,10,11) and col2 in (1000,10000)
@set condition_2 = col1 in (2,20,22) and col2 in (2000,20000)
@Set ctrl= 1

create table tbl_${ctrl}
select ${ctrl} as id, * from my_table where ${condition_${ctrl}}
```

When I run the select statement, it fails at `where` statement and resolves only `ctrl` variable and I get this error message:

```
SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 22:6 cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'condition_1' in expression specification
```

I think hive is ignoring the last closing curly bracket.
Any help would be appreciated!

I read the [Language Manual Variable Substitution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution) but it only show this:

```
set a=1;
set b=a;
set c=${hiveconf:${hiveconf:b}};
set c;
--uses nested variables.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think hive is ignoring the last closing curly bracket.

Because dollar sign needs to be placed before curly bracket.

Do it like in manual and it will work. Specify `hiveconf` namespace and do not forget about dollar sign before curly bracket: `${hiveconf:condition_${hiveconf:ctrl}}`

This example works fine:

```
set condition_1 = col1 in (1,10,11) and col2 in (1000,10000);
set condition_2 = col1 in (2,20,22) and col2 in (2000,20000);
Set ctrl= 1;

with Table1 as( 
SELECT stack (2,
1, 1000,
2, 2000
) AS  (col1, col2)
)

select ${hiveconf:ctrl} as id, t.* from Table1 t where ${hiveconf:condition_${hiveconf:ctrl}}
```

Comment: Hi! Tks for your answer. In my script I was using brackets correctly. I just mistyped the code in my question.

Comment: I tried to run your piece of code and it didnt work.
I'm using Dbeaver to run. Here is a screenshot: https://snipboard.io/EMU3q8.jpg 
In the first SS, I tried to run exactly as you posted.

2nd ScreenShot: https://snipboard.io/T1xksP.jpg
So, I tried to run the same way I was doing before (```@set```) and it shows a popup
This popup usually appears when I try to run a variable without declaring it first.

Comment: @arnaldoleandro Yes, In Dbeaver it may work differently, I'm not sure about Dbeaver. In pure Hive this works and you do not need `@set`.

Comment: Yes. In pure hive it did work. But I need my scripts to run in Dbeaver, unfortunately.